# why array is not sorted in below javacode?

Tags: java

when i run the code ,array p is not sorted. I cant figure out

why is this happening?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        //creating array p
        int[] p= new int[] {2,7,8,3,9,1,4,5,6,0 };

        //sort p[5] to p[9]
        Arrays.sort(p, 5, 9);
        for(int l=0;l<p.length;l++)
        {
            System.out.print(p[l]);
        }

    }
}
```

output is:2783914560

Comment: It is sorted from p[5] - p[9]

Answer (score 5):

You're specifically asking to sort the portion from p[5] to p[9] *exclusive* of the upper bound... so 4 elements, which are already in order (1, 4, 5, 6).

If you want to sort to p[9] *inclusive*, you should call

```
Arrays.sort(p, 5, 10);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int%3aA-int-int-):

> `toIndex` - the index of the last element, exclusive, to be sorted

Of course, that still won't sort the *whole* array - just the last part of it, so you'd end up with { 2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 0, 1, 4, 5, 6 }. To sort the whole array, just call `Arrays.sort(p)`.

Note that the pattern of specifying a range using an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound is *very* common in computing, and you should get used to it. Another common example is `String.substring`:

```
String text = "0123456789";
String substring = text.substring(0, 5); // 01234
```

Comment: indeed. for more detailed information, visit this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[],%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't sort the entire array. In this line:

```
Arrays.sort(p, 5, 9);
```

you are sorting the array only from the position 5 to 9. Use could use instead:

```
Arrays.sort(p, 0, p.length);
```

In this way you are sure that you are sorting the entire array from the first position (index zero) to the last position (the last parameter indicates the last exclusive index).

But it is easier to use:

```
Arrays.sort(p);
```

that automatically sort the entire array as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

From the java docs of `Arrays.sort()`

> The range to be sorted extends from index fromIndex, inclusive, to
>   index toIndex, exclusive.

I think you are expecting to include `index 9` as well in your sorting. In that case you need to pass `p.length (that is 10) instead of 9`.